# convert Raw in R to Char when it has nulls

Tags: r

When trying to use `rawToChar(varName)` method, it throws,

> Error in rawToChar(m) : embedded nul in string:
>   'X\n\0\0\0\002\0\003\002\003\0\002\003\

How do I still retrieve it?If your suggestion is to remove nulls with
 NA or may be 0 before storing, I am writing this data to HDFS using

```
writeToHDFS <- function(fileName){
   hdfs.init()
   modelfile <- hdfs.file(fileName, "w")
   hdfs.write(get(fileName), modelfile)
   hdfs.close(modelfile)
}
```

where `fileName` is a string and `get(fileName)` returns the variable value.

How do I do it in this case.  I tried removing nulls using is.na/is.null function but that did not help either and it still throws same error

Answer (score 0):

The 'nul' is not a null or NA, it is '00'. That's why is.na or is.null won't work.